# Load different view for Controller if the route contains language prefix (Dynamic loading of view)

Tags: angularjs, mvvm, multilingual, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

I am using **Dan Wahlin's AngularJS** tutorial as a seed project for angular.
The code can be found here:
https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManager

**I am having trouble making it function for two different languages.** 
For example. When the route is : `/en/customers` or `/customers` only, I want to show `customers.html` view which is in `/Views/` folder, If the route is `/fr/customers` I want to load the `customers.html` ng-view which is in `/Views/fr` directory. 
The problem is routes are registered in app.config. Once the routes are registered how can I change them to work for other languages?

Once the site is loaded and home page is displayed to the user, I have a link which says change language. Once the link is clicked I want all the routes to now have `/fr/routeName` instead of `/routeName`. How can I do that.
How am I going to remember the language and reroute all the routes to `/fr/routeName` instead of just the default `/routeName`.
I tried using `$location.search('lang','fr')` to append a querystring value once the user click change language button. But each time a link is clicked the querystring gets vanished. Also even if I have the query string, How am I going to tell Angular that from now on, use `/View/fr` as the base directory for Views instead of `/Views` only because the queryString contains `lang=fr`.

Earlier when I used to make MVVM applications using **Kendo's MVVM** framework , I used to put fr views in `/views/fr` folder with same name and english views in `/Views` directory. Then I checked in Viewmodel that if the querystring contains fr, I compiled fr template from `/View/fr` folder otherwise I loaded template from `/Views` folder.

*This is the **app.js** file which contains app.config:
[app.js](https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManager/blob/master/CustomerManager/app/app.js)

*Here is the **routeResolver** service which has the base directory for views hardcoded:
[routeResolver.js](https://github.com/DanWahlin/CustomerManager/blob/master/CustomerManager/app/customersApp/services/routeResolver.js)

**In short:**

**1)** How can I store user's selected language after he clicks a link or button, Is querystring the way to go? Or can I set the default route to point to /fr from a controller for every request from then onwards?
**2)** How can I tell angular to route to /Views/fr instead of /Views to get the fr View if the queryString contains lang=fr.

I am new to angular and very confused with services,factories,providers etc. Services are not available in config, We have to use Providers, While I dont have Providers in run blocks, instead we have to use Services. Its going to take time before I get a hold of it. I would appreciate any help. You can refer to the git hub project of Dan Wahlin and please tell me how can I change it to respond for other language also. Currently the View directory is hardcoded to `var viewsDirectory = '/app/customersApp/views/',` in routeResolver.js. How can I make it to /views/fr on user click once the app has loaded and user selects French language as default.

Comment: have you considered moving the app entry up one directory...so `lang` is the app root? Then a global variable/angular constant can be set based on `lang`. All other routing would be relative to to the language root and therefore the same angular routing paths would be used regardless of language

Comment: The thing is. I want to make it work for both the languages based on user's selected option. Setting it up one directory would mean either one of them will run for a single instance. I am not sure if I follow you. I think I should be able to tell angular in the controller to change route to /fr/routeName on userClick of language change from then on onwards for "every" route. Changing the directory structure is not going to help I think. Please tell me if am not understanding your point.

Comment: my thinking would be virtual directory for language on server. `example.com/en` would be base. Then it's easy to telll angular which templates using one variable and other routing is all relative regardless of language

Comment: When user switches language do a page reload into other language virtual directory and the language global variable gets set to new lang. Or prefix every route in routeConfig and `$routeParams` always has lang. `templateUrl` accepts a function

Comment: Um. I dont think i can do that. Earlier in our kendo MVVM projects we used to load respective views based on querystring. I dont want to handle it on server side. I want something like this : `example.com/index.html/en/` There has got to be a way to set the default route to `example.com/index.html/fr/` instead of `example.com/index.html/` . I am new to this angular & clueless of changing the default route which I think is a trivial thing. Thanks for the help though man, appreciate it.

Comment: one other suggestion is upgrade router to ui-router. It allows parent states and would make it quite simple that way

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about $routeParams and templateUrl. What should i do, I am willing to prefix every route in routeConfig for every french routes. How can I set a default route to index.html/fr/routeName instaed of index.html/routename?

Comment: You define url with `'/:lang/customers'` as example for a customer path. Read up on `$routeParams` which would then be object with `lang` property and accessible throughout app

Comment: Hey charlie, I can add routes using `:lang` in my app.js. But How am I going to hit/access them based on user's selected option. For example Once the application has started. Routes would already have been registered. Say for instance I have a route `/:lang/customers`, How can I tell angular to set `:lang` to `$rootScope.lang` so that the respective link or button's url becomes `/fr/customers` from inside the controller.

Comment: Also please check this question I have posted with a more specific problem. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32681571/angularjs-dynamically-change-template-url-based-on-rootscopes-value-in-routec`

Comment: `$routeParams` is available anywhere in app and has that property in it. So for example can use it in `templateUrl:function` and can access it in any controller or directive. If you used `ui-router` would make it even simpler

Comment: Thanks for the help charlie. What I ended up doing is, I stored the user's selected option of lang in document.cookie on user's button click, & then I reloaded the page using $window, & got user's selected lang in document.cookie which was set earlier in the controller. Now I changed the views directory from /views to /views/fr in my app.config. It might not be the standard way but did the trick, $rootScope was not available in app config. If there is an alternate approach please tell me. Also I was not in a position to use ui-router. That would have been the better choice I guess. Thanks.